# I cannot open gdb using M-x gdb on my mac

Tags: macos, emacs, gdb

My OS is OSX 10.9.4, and I'm using gdb 7.7.1.

I can open gdb in shell mode in emacs.
but cannot open gdb using `M-x gdb`. Emacs just says "No such file or directory, gdb". Why does this happen? Do I need to configure the M-x command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `PATH` is set differently in the shell and in Emacs.  You can get around that by specifying the path explicitly in `M-x gdb`.

- In the shell, type `which gdb`, and note what it prints, something like `/foo/bar/gdb`.
- Then, type `M-x gdb`.  The minibuffer asks for `Run gdb (like this):`, and the default value is `gdb -i=mi`. Edit the command line in the minibuffer, replacing the initial `gdb` with the result of `which gdb`.

If that works, you can customize `gud-gdb-command-line` and set the correct path once and forever.

Comment: thanks. i try it,but it dose not work.the result of "which gdb" is "usr/local/bin/gdb", then i type "m-x usr/local/bin/gdb", it tell me "[no match]".

Comment: You'd still use `M-x gdb`.  I tried to clarify the answer; see if that helps.

Comment: sorry.I am not enough reputation to vote up your answer.

Comment: You can "accept" it, by clicking the check mark below the vote arrows. That gives you 2 reputation points as well.